# Change a value in a column in several data frames with different columns length in R

Tags: r

I am trying to change the name of a country in several data frames at the same time, but each data frame has different column lengths. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(country = c('Austria','UK'), year = c(2015,2012), data = c(10,12))
df2 <- data.frame(country = c('Austria','UK'), year = c(2015,2012), prop = c(0.5,0.2), gender = c('male','female'))
df3 <- data.frame(country = c('Austria','UK'), year = c(2015,2012))
```

I need to change "UK" to "United Kingdom" in all the data frames. I am doing the following:

```
aList <- list(df1,df2,df3)

lapply(aList, function(df){
  df$new_country <- df%>% mutate (new_country = ifelse(df$country == 'UK', 'United Kingdom', df$country))
})
```

But I do not get the changes. I see this in the console:

```
[[1]]
  country year data    new_country
1 Austria 2015   10              1
2      UK 2012   12 United Kingdom

[[2]]
  country year prop gender    new_country
1 Austria 2015  0.5   male              1
2      UK 2012  0.2 female United Kingdom

[[3]]
  country year    new_country
1 Austria 2015              1
2      UK 2012 United Kingdom
```

But I do not see the values in the list when I open the list, and the value of Austria is 1 and it should be Austria. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to assign it to aList.  i.e. `aList <- lapply(aList, ...`  Also, you don't need `df$new_country <-` as you are already using `mutate`

Comment: Thanks akrun... and about the Austria being 1 in the new_country column? How can I change it to Austria? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have a `factor` column which gets coerced to integer storage values.  Do the `as.character(df$country)` in the `ifelse`

Comment: Thanks a lot  akrun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data.table solution:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(country = c('Austria','UK'), year = c(2015,2012), data = c(10,12))
df2 <- data.table(country = c('Austria','UK'), year = c(2015,2012), prop = c(0.5,0.2), gender = c('male','female'))
df3 <- data.table(country = c('Austria','UK'), year = c(2015,2012))

aList <- list(df1,df2,df3)

bList <- lapply(aList, function(x) x[,lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub("UK", "United Kingdom", x))])
```

Comment: Thanks Alexvonrass!